# Calculate relative shares of a flow from multiple data sources to multiple data targets

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

How can I best calculate the "from to" percentage in the m:n year on year situation below? Logically or preferably using a Python module. What is the correct terminology for this type of calculation?

```
region year people 
A - 2018 - 100 
B - 2018 - 200
C - 2018 - 300
X - 2019 - 150
Y - 2019 - 160
Z - 2019 - 310

network / flow
A -> Z
B -> X
B -> Z
C -> Y
C -> Z
```

I want to calculate the % of people from the old to the new region. I know the number of people per region per year. Applying the calculated % to the people in old should result in a calculated number of people in new as close as possible to the actual number of people in new.

Context: I know the census per region in 2018 and 2019. The totals have changed. The region definitions have also changed. I know which regions have changed from one definition to another. Some are easy, e.g. A to Z: 100% moves from A to Z. Others are harder because one source has multiple targets and the targets are fed from different other sources. B moves partly to X and partly to Z. C moves to Y and Z. Z receives from A, B and C.

Note: I also know the % of land surface that moved from the source to the destination regions, I might use this as weight, but if I solely apply the % of surface then the calculated census numbers based on 2018 and the surface % are very different from the actual 2019 data.

Background: I want to calculate the 'from to number' because I also have much more data that I want to apply the percentage to (different topics, e.g. age groups) as well as data from more previous years. There are 500 changed regions on a total of 10000 regions yearly. I want to show calculated history for these regions rather than no history.

The calculation will likely not result in an exact anwer, I strive for the best possible approximation.

Writing it down like this may help?:

```
X = bB
Y = dC
Z = aA + cB + eC

a = 1
b + c = 1
d + e = 1

A + B + C ~ X + Y + Z
```

Many thanks in advance! Wouter

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `graph-theory` or with `graphing-functions`?

Comment: Thanks. I tagged graphing-functions because I think that I may use graph software like networkx to recognise 'communities' within my data to reduce the size of the 'from to' groups that the calculations take place for. And I hope that there is a function to calculate weight that I can use here. It may be wrong. At least 1 tag is required. This is new to me. What would be a better tag?

Comment: I think that `statistics` is a far better choice.

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate? The number of people who were in region 1 in one year, but in region 2 the next?

Comment: I want to calculate the % of people from the old to the new region. I know the number of people per region per year. The % old to new depends on the other flows of old to new. And the sum of old is different from the sum of new. So applying the calculated % to the people in old should result in a calculated number of people in new as close as possible to the actual number of people in new.